# How to use ruby to parse the json response given by foursquare API

Tags: json, api, foursquare

I am using foursquare API to search for a particular venue. I use the following url:
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/venue_id?oauth_token=Access_token

The response given by the website is json.

Then I use the following code trying to parse this json  response using ruby:

```
require 'rest-open-uri'
require 'json'

url = 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/venue_id?oauth_token=Access_token'

buffer = open(url, "UserAgent" => "Ruby-Wget").read

result = JSON.parse(buffer)
```

Here are the error code I get:

C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:678:in `connect': SSL_con
nect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verif
y failed (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:678:in`bloc
k in connect'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:44:in `timeou
t'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:89:in`timeou
t'

Does this error code mean that I cannot open this url because it starts with "https"? Is there any way that I could use to open this url and parse the json response?

Thanks ahead!

Answer (score 16):

This should work:

```
gem install httparty
```

then

```
require 'httparty'
require 'json'

response = HTTParty.get("https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/vid", 
:query => {:oauth_token => "abc"})

json = JSON.parse(response.body)
```

Answer (score -3):

RUBY is case sensitive.
require 'json' # json must be lower case

JSON.parse()
for example 
JSON.parse(response.body) # JSON must be all upper-case